# Map is a raw type when assigning Map.class. But assigning a type results in a mismatch. How do I parameterize Map.class?

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

I receive a warning here that Map is a raw type.

```
// Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be parameterized
Class<Map> c = Map.class;
```

But if I parameterize the type, then I get a mismatch:

```
// Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Map> to Class<Map<Object,Object>>
Class<Map<Object, Object>> c = Map.class;
```

I have tried a few variations, but I can't find any way to parameterize the right side of the expression (`Map.class`) to satisfy the left side, which is parameterized.

How do I parameterize `Map.class` in this instance?

In this case I am passing it to a method with a signature:

```
public <T> T method(Class<T> type) {
   return (T) otherMethod(type);
}
```

I only want to provide the `Map` type, as I don't know what kind of map is used internally, and this detail is not important. I am trying to resolve the warning I get when calling the method:

```
// Type safety: The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,Object>
Map<String, Object> a = method(Map.class);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `c`? Depending on that, it is safe to leave it as `Class<Map> c = Map.class;`.

Comment: I've added some further clarification to my use case. It should be safe as it is, but I would like to know if there is a way to satisfy the compiler without having to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suppresses the warning at the call site:

```
public static <T> T method(Class<? super T> type) {
    return (T) otherMethod(type);
}
```

There is still an unchecked cast warning on the expression `(T) otherMethod(type)`, but I believe that is unavoidable.

Comment: The source of this warning is from SnakeYAML. They already suppress this warning on their end, but use `Class<T>`. Is this an oversight in their public interface or is it a problem with my use of their library? https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/src/5761670cd73b6f41cfc906a5ba722bb6bf1f3e17/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml.java#lines-456

Comment: I don't use the library, so I can't really say. After a brief look at the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation), it looks like they intend the `loadAs` method to be used with JavaBeans rather than collections.

Answer (score 0):

`Map.class` is of `Class<Map>`, which is not `Class<Map<Object, Object>`. You could use `Class<? super Map<Object, Object>> c = Map.class;`, because every `Map<Object, Object>` is also a `Map` (but not the other way round)

Comment: This does answer the part of my question on how to perform the assignment without any warning, but not the method call. I thought that solving the warning as part of the expression would satisfy the warning with the message call, but it still complains of a type mismatch: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#1-of ? super Map<Object,Object> to Map<Object,Object>`.

Comment: @Zhro your other method needs to be changed to co-/contravariant too, so it can handle generic types where the type parameters are not an exact match. Or, you'll change the method to work with a raw `Class`. So probably `method(Class<? extends T> type)` or `method(Class<? super T> type)`. Without `otherMethod`, your given method already works though. Generics in Java can be very annoying …